# How to deploy SharePoint solutions using different versions of ajax extensions in a common SharePoint server?

Tags: sharepoint, asp.net-ajax

We have a common SharePoint server which runs an internal SharePoint site. Our teams deploy their SharePoint products in the server and add it to our site. Some products user .net framework 2.0 and some products use .net 3.5. So they enable ajax extenisons for the site for .net 2.0 which adds the entries for the assembly System.Web.Extensions version 1.0.61025.0 where as our version will be 3.5.0.0. Because of the difference we get an ambiguous error while running the web site.

How can we deploy different products using different versions of Ajax extensions in the same site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should upgrade all your servers to 3.5, any other workaround is useless now. If you still have to do that, I would compile everything under 1.0.61025 and add to the web.config of the servers running 3.5 entries mapping dll versions (just like they do in SharePoint 2007 for mapping DLL for web parts compiled under SharePoint 2003, take a look at the web.config, it's self-explanatory.